# How to chain a dereference in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'd like a method `t.find_first [:a, :b, :c], [:d, :e]` for a hash `t` that returns the first set of keys that dereference.

For the example above, it would be the equivalent of `t.try(:[], :a).try(:[], :b).try(:[], :c) || t.try(:[], :d).try(:[], :e)`.

Currently I'm at:

```
def find_first t, *keysets
  keysets.each do |keys|
    val = val || keys.inject(t){ |h, key| h.try(:[], key) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you taken a crack at writing it more procedurally? Your long-form version could be collapsed into a series of calls that iterate over the groups.

Comment: I tried something with `inject`, but it didn't look right.

Comment: @Will Post whatever you've tried. Often the solution is just within reach and you only need a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to create a special method for this.

Ruby < 2.3

```
value   = t.try(:[], :a).try(:[], :b).try(:[], :c)
value ||= t.try(:[], :d).try(:[], :e)
```

Ruby >= 2.3:

```
value   = t&.[](:a)&.[](:b)&.[](:c)
value ||= t&.[](:d)&.[](:e)
```

And while this question was posed rather obliquely, it looks from the method signature that you might be trying to walk into a nested hash like a params object.

If that is the case, you should take a look at [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) for this. You can always monkeypatch it in if you aren't on 2.3

```
value   = t.dig(:a, :b, :c)
value ||= t.dig(:d, :e)
```

Another pattern for walking into hashes without `Hash#dig` is something like this:

```
params.fetch(:a, {}).fetch(:b, {})[:c]
```

Comment: I want to be able to pass in arbitrary arrays of keys. `dig` looks really useful though.

Comment: @Will just write as many `||=` assignments as you need. Also, `Array#dig` exists too.

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly elegant I suppose, but sometimes less magic is better.

```
class FindFirst
  def self.find_first(t, *keysets)
    keysets.each do |keyset|
      return keyset if can_dereference_chain?(t, keyset)
    end
    nil
  end

  def self.can_dereference_chain?(t, keyset)
    keys = keyset.dup
    key = keys.shift
    if value = t[key]
      keys.empty? ? true : can_dereference_chain?(value, keys)
    else
      false
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe FindFirst do
  subject { FindFirst }
  let(:t) { {a:{b:{c:1}}} }
  let(:keyset_1) { [:a, :b, :c] }
  let(:keyset_2) { [:a, :b, :d] }

  describe "when first keyset works" do
    it "returns the first keyset" do
      expect(subject.find_first(t, keyset_1)).to eq keyset_1
      expect(subject.find_first(t, keyset_1, keyset_2)).to eq keyset_1
    end
  end

  describe "when no keysets work" do
    it "returns nil" do
      expect(subject.find_first(t, keyset_2)).to eq nil
      expect(subject.find_first(t, [])).to eq nil
      expect(subject.find_first({}, keyset_1, keyset_2, [])).to eq nil
    end
  end

  describe "when first keyset does not work" do
    describe "and second keyset does" do
      it "returns the second keyset" do
        expect(subject.find_first(t, keyset_2, keyset_1)).to eq keyset_1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = { a: :d, c: :f, d: :e, f: :a }
possible_sequences = [[:a, :b, :c], [:d, :e, :f], [:a, :d, :e]]

possible_sequences.find { |a| a[1..-1].reduce(a[0]) { |t,k| k if (t && h[t]==k) } }
  #=> [:a, :d, :e]
```